# Use plus and minus icons from TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a custom control that the user can expand and contract. For the most intuitive user experience I would like to use the [plus](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC133569.gif) and [minus](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC119272.gif) icons that the user may have encountered before. They are available to the [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366759%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) control so theoretically I should be able to access them directly for my control. I am just not sure how.

Comment: Just use ImageButtons and search for free Collapse/Expand icons online. EDIT: Nvm, you got the icons already, just use ImageButton control, or simple Image controls

Comment: @HanletEscaño I feel it would be bad form to include images in my application that are already on the users hard drive. Even though they may be insignificant in size.

Comment: Buttons that contain images will not give the best experience here. I would draw there in your custom control in code - but rest assured this will not be easy. Look for examples/tutorials on Code Project...

Comment: @Killercam I am already going to have to draw my custom control manually due to it's nature and am familiar with doing that. I just need to access the image to draw it.

Comment: What do you mean? The plus and minus on the tree are controls in there own right. You will have to looking to drawing these controls yourself...

Comment: @Killercam The [TreeView documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366759%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) implies that the plus and minus buttons are images named plus.gif and minus.gif. I just want to know where these files are located.

Comment: @Fr33dan That documentation is for web pages. You have this tagged as WinForms. WinForms controls are drawn using GDI+. There aren't any stock images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using the [VisualStyle classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.treeview.branch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
  VisualStyleRenderer treeClose = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.TreeView.Glyph.Closed);
  treeClose.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(16, 16, 16, 16));
  TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "Closed Branch", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, new Point(32, 16), Color.Black);

  VisualStyleRenderer treeOpen = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.TreeView.Glyph.Opened);
  treeOpen.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(16, 32, 16, 16));
  TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "Opened Branch", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, new Point(32,32), Color.Black);

  base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

[image]

If the VisualStyles aren't supported for your application, you would have to manually draw them yourself, which isn't too hard.  A rectangle plus a line or two in the middle.

Comment: I knew there had to be some way to draw it without adding any images as it is such a common display element. It works a bit different than I was expecting but this is exactly what I wanted.